# Batch fit image in Linux (e.g. GIMP)

Tags: linux, image-processing, gimp

How can I batch fit an image under Linux?

Please note that I explicitly ask for batch fitting images independent of the actual orientation of the image (e.g. always fit to 800x600 px max, taken into account different orientations of the images).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [imagemagick convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/).

Comment: Your question is quite confusing - you say `independent of orientation` meaning `not dependent on orientation`, then you say `taking orientation into account` meaning `depedent on orientation`. Which is it? What does an image 1000 px wide by 2000 px tall get resized to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this task and many others with imagemagick

For example

```
 ls *.jpg | xargs -I'{}' convert -resize 800X600 -quality 80 {} {}
```